# How to fix only one item from a list being added to a file

Tags: python, list, python-requests, operating-system

I'm trying to create a way in which I scan through a bunch of folders and add their names to a list, then take out a specific bit of the filename (numbers) and add them to a `.txt` file.

I've currently got to a stage where I have a list full of the folders' names, and I can abstract the numbers out of the string. However, adding them to a `.txt` file seems to be an issue. It only adds one item.

```py
    def generateSetFile(self, path=None):
        if not path:
            print("Missing required argument: 'filename'")
        folders = []
        # iterating through path
        for r, d, f in os.walk(path): # where R=ROOT, D=DIRECTORIES,F=FILES
            for folder in d:
                folders.append(os.path.join(r, folder))

        print(folders) # definitely returns more than one index

        # adding all songnames to a txt file
        for f in folders:
            songname = f.split(" ")[0].split("\\") # getting numbers
            with open("mysongs.txt", "w+") as fp:
                fp.write(f"{songname[1]}\n") # newline for next item
        print("Done!")
```

No error messages are thrown at me and it isn't the first item that goes there, but the last item. My only idea is that every item overwrites one another, and if that's the case how do I go about changing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that at every iteration you're overwriting your file. You should change this:

```
# adding all songnames to a txt file
    for f in folders:
        songname = f.split(" ")[0].split("\\") # getting numbers
        with open("mysongs.txt", "w+") as fp:
            fp.write(f"{songname[1]}\n") # newline for next item
    print("Done!")
```

By this:

```
# adding all songnames to a txt file
with open("mysongs.txt", "w+") as fp:
    for f in folders:
        songname = f.split(" ")[0].split("\\") # getting numbers
        fp.write(f"{songname[1]}\n") # newline for next item
print("Done!")
```